# How to print images in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to print images in Landscape mode. Tried to set orientation property of UIPrintInfor equals UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape. But the output likes print in Portrait mode. Here is my code:

```
NSData *dataToPrint = [_splitter dataForImage:_currentFileIndex];       
_printController.printingItem = data;   

if ([UIPrintInfo class]) 
{       
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];       
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;                        
    //printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;
    _printController.printInfo = printInfo;     
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note from docs about [UIPrintInfoOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPrintInfo/orientation)

> UIKit ignores this property when printable content is assigned to the
>   printingItem or printingItems properties of the shared
>   UIPrintInteractionController object. It determines the orientation
>   based on the type of content.

I assume this line `_printController.printingItem = data;` just the same and under this exception.

Comment: I means this property can set when we print text and what else?